# Sphinx installation centos7

Tags: centos7, sphinx

I just updated sphinx to the latest version on a dedicated server running with centos 7, but after hours of search I can't find the problem.

The sphinx index has created well, but I can't start search daemon. I got this messages all the time :

```
systemctl status searchd.service
searchd.service - SphinxSearch Search Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2018-03-24 21:14:09 CET; 3min 4s ago
Process: 17865 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown sphinx.sphinx /var/run/sphinx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 17863 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sphinx (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Mar 24 21:14:09  systemd[1]: Starting SphinxSearch Search Engine...
Mar 24 21:14:09  systemd[1]: searchd.service start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 24 21:14:09  systemd[1]: Failed to start SphinxSearch Search Engine.
Mar 24 21:14:09  systemd[1]: Unit searchd.service entered failed state.
Mar 24 21:14:09  systemd[1]: searchd.service failed.
```

I have really no idea where this problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

In your systemd service file (mine is in /usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service) comment out:

`/bin/chown sphinx.sphinx /var/run/sphinx
/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sphinx manually`

(you can run these commands manually if it's not done yet).

Then change from

`Type=forking`

to

`Type=simple`

Then do `systemctl daemon-reload` and you can start/stop/status the service:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service
[Unit]
Description=SphinxSearch Search Engine
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=sphinx
Group=sphinx
# Run ExecStartPre with root-permissions
PermissionsStartOnly=true
#ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sphinx
#ExecStartPre=/bin/chown sphinx.sphinx /var/run/sphinx
# Run ExecStart with User=sphinx / Group=sphinx
ExecStart=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --stopwait
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGTERM
SendSIGKILL=no
LimitNOFILE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
PIDFile=/var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sphinx.service
Alias=sphinxsearch.service

[root@server ~]# systemctl start searchd
[root@server ~]# systemctl status searchd
● searchd.service - SphinxSearch Search Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-03-25 10:41:24 EDT; 4s ago
  Process: 111091 ExecStop=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --stopwait (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 112030 (searchd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/searchd.service
           ├─112029 /usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
           └─112030 /usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf

Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: Sphinx 2.3.2-id64-beta (4409612)
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: Sphinx 2.3.2-id64-beta (4409612)
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: precaching index 'test1'
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: WARNING: index 'test1': prealloc: failed to open /var/lib/sphinx/test1.sph: No such file or directory...T SERVING
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: precaching index 'testrt'
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com systemd[1]: searchd.service: Supervising process 112030 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@server ~]# systemctl stop searchd
[root@server ~]# systemctl status searchd
● searchd.service - SphinxSearch Search Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-03-25 10:41:36 EDT; 1s ago
  Process: 112468 ExecStop=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --stopwait (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 112030

Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: WARNING: index 'test1': prealloc: failed to open /var/lib/sphinx/test1.sph: No such file or directory...T SERVING
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com searchd[112026]: precaching index 'testrt'
Mar 25 10:41:24 server.domain.com systemd[1]: searchd.service: Supervising process 112030 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
Mar 25 10:41:33 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Stopping SphinxSearch Search Engine...
Mar 25 10:41:33 server.domain.com searchd[112468]: [Sun Mar 25 10:41:33.183 2018] [112468] using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
Mar 25 10:41:33 server.domain.com searchd[112468]: [Sun Mar 25 10:41:33.183 2018] [112468] stop: successfully sent SIGTERM to pid 112030
Mar 25 10:41:36 server.domain.com systemd[1]: searchd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 25 10:41:36 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Stopped SphinxSearch Search Engine.
Mar 25 10:41:36 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Unit searchd.service entered failed state.
Mar 25 10:41:36 server.domain.com systemd[1]: searchd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your solution, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: @PolinaGuseva So you have exactly the same service file now, did systemctl daemon-reload, but still can't start the daemon? What does the status command say now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found the solution that worked for me.

I have edited my "/etc/systemd/system/sphinx.service" to look like

```
[Unit]
Description=SphinxSearch Search Engine
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=sphinx
Group=sphinx
RuntimeDirectory=sphinxsearch
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0775
# Run ExecStart with User=sphinx / Group=sphinx
ExecStart=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --stopwait
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGTERM
SendSIGKILL=no
LimitNOFILE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
#PIDFile=/var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid
PIDFile=/var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sphinx.service
Alias=sphinxsearch.service
```

In that case my searchd is able to survive the reboot. The solution from previous post have the problem with searchd starting after reboot before the /var/run/sphinxsearch dir was deleting after reboot in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that RHEL (CentOS) 7 does not perceive the "Infinity" value of the "TimeoutStartSec"parameter. You must set a numeric value. For Example, TimeoutStartSec=600